# JS - Force function to run after other functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JS Script I am building that will get certain ID's from JSON, display those ID's and then remove the found ones from the array and move on to the next function, which will test additional values.

My problem is that the code in the second function is evaluating before the first function finishes and causes the full array to appear, rather than the updated array with the removed values after the first function has finished.

You can see in my Console Log, that the first line (num=) on line 126 evaluates before the erase function is called, even though line 126 is within the second function and has not been called yet.

`num=,111,222,8378102505047 - ScriptNewID.js:126
 ["111", "222", "8378102505047"]- ScriptNewID.js:220
 ["111", "222"] ScriptNewID.js:221`

How am I able to force these values not to evaluate until the first function is finished?

Thanks in advance!

```js
// Version 1

 getEmptyArticles();

function getEmptyArticles() {
 
 articleArray = [];
 
 var empytyBaseURL = "scripts/get-empty-rows.php";

   $.ajax({
    url: empytyBaseURL,
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 7000
   }).done(function(json){
    token = json;
     for( var i = 0; i < token.length; i++) {
     articleArray.push(token[i]);
     }
    API1(articleArray);
    API2(articleArray);
    
   }).fail(function(){
    alert("ERROR: Could Not Get Empty Articles");
   }).always(function() {
    //setTimeout(getEmptyArticles, 200000);
    //articleArray.length = 0;
   });  
   
 }
 
function API1(articleIDs) {

 var BaseURL = "OMITTED";
 var IDs =  returnCIDs(articleIDs, ";");
 var APIKey = "OMITTED";
 var APIURL = BaseURL + IDs + "?api_key=" + APIKey;
    
  $.ajax({
   url: APIURL,
   dataType: 'json',
   timeout: 7000
  }).done(function(json){
   token = json;
   obj = token.result;
   API1Success(obj);
  }).fail(function(){
   API1Error();
  }); 
 
  function API1Success(obj) {
   var lastScan = "";
   
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
     if(obj[i].LabelNo) {
      //ADD RESULTS TO TABLE HERE
     } else if (obj[i].LabelNumber) {
      var arrayIndex = articleArray.indexOf(obj[i].LabelNumber);
       for (var x = 0; x < obj[i].Scans.length; x++) {
        lastScan = obj[i].Scans[x].StatusDescription; 
       }
      
    //POST DATA TO TABLE 1 DATABASE URL 
            
      var id = obj[i].LabelNumber;
      lastScan = lastScan.replace(/'/g, "");
      var articles = "None Specified";
      var Name = "OMITTED";
      
      postTable1Data(id, lastScan, articles, Name);     
    
    //POST DATA TO TABLE 2 DATABASE URL
     
      for (var x = 0; x < obj[i].Scans.length; x++) {
       var eventID = obj[i].LabelNumber;
       var eventProdType = "";
       var eventBadTime = moment(obj[i].Scans[x].Date, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
       var eventGoodTime = eventBadTime.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
       var eventLocation = obj[i].Scans[x].Name;
       var scan = obj[i].Scans[x].StatusDescription;
       scan = scan.replace(/'/g, "");
       
       postTable2Data(eventID, eventProdType, eventGoodTime, eventLocation, scan);
      }
    
    //REMOVE GOOD URL FROM ARRAY
     eraseFoundArticle(obj[i].LabelNumber);
     }
    }

  }

  function API1Error() {
   console.log("ERROR CONNECTING TO THE API");
  } 
}

function API2(articleIDs) {

 
 var tPHPURL = "omitted";
 var tIDs =  "num=" + returnCIDs(articleIDs, ",");
 
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST" ,
  url: tPHPURL ,
  data: tIDs
  }).done(function(json){
   obj = json;
   tSuccess(obj);
  }).fail(function(){
   tError();
  }); 
 
 function tSuccess(obj) {
      
       
  //ERROR LOGGING
  
  if (obj.errors.length > 1) {
   for (var i = 0; i < obj.errors.length; i++) {
    
    var errors = obj.errors[i];
    var strErrors = errors.split(" ");
    var id = strErrors[1];
    var c = "omitted";
    
    postErrorData(id, c)
    
   }
  }
  
  //SUCCESS LOGGING
  
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.tatConnotes.length; i++) {
   var id = obj.tatnotes[i].connote;
   var status = obj.tatConnotes[i].lastEventStatus;
   var articles = obj.tatConnotes[i].actualItems;
   var cName = obj.tatConnotes[i].tBusinessName;
   
   eraseFoundArticle(id);

   
   postTable1Data(id, status, articles, cName);

    for (var x = 0; x < obj.tatnotes[i].cEvents.length; x++) {
     var cId = obj.tatnotes[i].cEvents[x].connote;
     var cType = obj.tatnotes[i].cDescription;
     var badDateTime = moment(obj.tatConnotes[i].cEvents[x].eventDateTime, "ddd D/MM/YYYY hh:mm A");
     var cDateTime = badDateTime.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var cLocation = obj.tatnotes[i].cEvents[x].location;
     var cDescription = obj.tatnotes[i].consignmentEvents[x].eventDescription;
     
     postTable2Data(cId, cType, cDateTime,cLocation ,cDescription);
    }
  
  }
 

 }
 
 function tError() {
  //ADD BACKUP FUNCTION HERE
 }

}

function postTable1Data(id, status, articles, couriername) {
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "scripts/update.php",
    data: //INSERT DATA HERE - OMITTED
    success: //INSERT DATA HERE - OMITTED
   });  
 }

function postTable2Data(id, type, datetime, location, description) {

   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "scripts/update.php",
    data: //INSERT DATA HERE - OMITTED
    success: //INSERT DATA HERE - OMITTED
   }); 

 }
 
function postErrorData(id, courier) {
  
  //POST ERROR DATA - OMITTED
  
 }
  
function eraseFoundArticle(id) {
  var arrayIndex = articleArray.indexOf(id);
   articleArray.splice(arrayIndex,1);

 }
  

function returnCIDs(articleIDs, seperator) {
   var cArticleIDs = "";
   for (var i = 0; i < articleIDs.length; i++) { 
    var cArticleIDs = cArticleIDs + seperator + articleIDs[i] ;
   }
   return cArticleIDs;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you define your functions?

Comment: Use callbacks for your asynchronous functions.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144161/run-function-after-another-one-completes

Comment: We will need to see the actual code involved to understand where you have async operations and why your code isn't executing in the order you want.  We MUST see the code to do anything other than guess or offer highly generic things to think about.  If you want a specific answer that applies to your actual situation, we must see all the relevant code.

Comment: [this could be a good tutorial](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) for you

Comment: @JimmyP like Bergi said you have asynchronous functions (everything in an AJAX request) which will start and then code will continue to execute before the AJAX finishes.  Just keep that in mind.  Also, we don't know which of all those functions you're talking about.

Comment: Hi @JBaczuk, Thanks for the response. My issue is that the tID's variable in the API2 function runs before all of the functions in API1 complete. At the end of API1, I run a function to remove the good url from the array, expecting it to update the array (which it does) and then run API2 and then get the tID's variable (which holds the updated array from API1). The issue is that tID's in API2 is evaluated before API1 is finished, which results in an old array.

Comment: @JimmyP, I just posted an answer that may or may not work, since I can't test it, but I think you're problem is that your AJAX request in API1 might not finish before API2 executes, so I put the function call API2(articleIDs) in the callback for the AJAX request in API1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (untested).  It won't call API2 until API1 completes:

```
// Version 1

    getEmptyArticles();

function getEmptyArticles() {

    articleArray = [];

    var empytyBaseURL = "scripts/get-empty-rows.php";

            $.ajax({
                url: empytyBaseURL,
                dataType: 'json',
                timeout: 7000
            }).done(function(json){
                token = json;
                    for( var i = 0; i < token.length; i++) {
                    articleArray.push(token[i]);
                    }
                API1(articleArray);

            }).fail(function(){
                alert("ERROR: Could Not Get Empty Articles");
            }).always(function() {
                //setTimeout(getEmptyArticles, 200000);
                //articleArray.length = 0;
            });     

 }

function API1(articleIDs) {

    var BaseURL = "OMITTED";
    var IDs =  returnCIDs(articleIDs, ";");
    var APIKey = "OMITTED";
    var APIURL = BaseURL + IDs + "?api_key=" + APIKey;

        $.ajax({
            url: APIURL,
            dataType: 'json',
            timeout: 7000
        }).done(function(json){
            token = json;
            obj = token.result;
            API1Success(obj, articleIDs);
        }).fail(function(){
            API1Error();
        }); 

        function API1Success(obj, articleIDs) {
            var lastScan = "";

                for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                    if(obj[i].LabelNo) {
                        //ADD RESULTS TO TABLE HERE
                    } else if (obj[i].LabelNumber) {
                        var arrayIndex = articleArray.indexOf(obj[i].LabelNumber);
                            for (var x = 0; x < obj[i].Scans.length; x++) {
                                lastScan = obj[i].Scans[x].StatusDescription;   
                            }

                //POST DATA TO TABLE 1 DATABASE URL 

                        var id = obj[i].LabelNumber;
                        lastScan = lastScan.replace(/'/g, "");
                        var articles = "None Specified";
                        var Name = "OMITTED";

                        postTable1Data(id, lastScan, articles, Name);                   

                //POST DATA TO TABLE 2 DATABASE URL

                        for (var x = 0; x < obj[i].Scans.length; x++) {
                            var eventID = obj[i].LabelNumber;
                            var eventProdType = "";
                            var eventBadTime = moment(obj[i].Scans[x].Date, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
                            var eventGoodTime = eventBadTime.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                            var eventLocation = obj[i].Scans[x].Name;
                            var scan = obj[i].Scans[x].StatusDescription;
                            scan = scan.replace(/'/g, "");

                            postTable2Data(eventID, eventProdType, eventGoodTime, eventLocation, scan);
                        }

                //REMOVE GOOD URL FROM ARRAY
                    eraseFoundArticle(obj[i].LabelNumber);
                    }
                }
            API2(articleIDs);

        }

        function API1Error() {
            console.log("ERROR CONNECTING TO THE API");
        }   

}

function API2(articleIDs) {


    var tPHPURL = "omitted";
    var tIDs =  "num=" + returnCIDs(articleIDs, ",");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST" ,
        url: tPHPURL ,
        data: tIDs
        }).done(function(json){
            obj = json;
            tSuccess(obj);
        }).fail(function(){
            tError();
        }); 

    function tSuccess(obj) {


        //ERROR LOGGING

        if (obj.errors.length > 1) {
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.errors.length; i++) {

                var errors = obj.errors[i];
                var strErrors = errors.split(" ");
                var id = strErrors[1];
                var c = "omitted";

                postErrorData(id, c)

            }
        }

        //SUCCESS LOGGING

        for (var i = 0; i < obj.tatConnotes.length; i++) {
            var id = obj.tatnotes[i].connote;
            var status = obj.tatConnotes[i].lastEventStatus;
            var articles = obj.tatConnotes[i].actualItems;
            var cName = obj.tatConnotes[i].tBusinessName;

            eraseFoundArticle(id);


            postTable1Data(id, status, articles, cName);

                for (var x = 0; x < obj.tatnotes[i].cEvents.length; x++) {
                    var cId = obj.tatnotes[i].cEvents[x].connote;
                    var cType = obj.tatnotes[i].cDescription;
                    var badDateTime = moment(obj.tatConnotes[i].cEvents[x].eventDateTime, "ddd D/MM/YYYY hh:mm A");
                    var cDateTime = badDateTime.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                    var cLocation = obj.tatnotes[i].cEvents[x].location;
                    var cDescription = obj.tatnotes[i].consignmentEvents[x].eventDescription;

                    postTable2Data(cId, cType, cDateTime,cLocation ,cDescription);
                }

        }


    }

    function tError() {
        //ADD BACKUP FUNCTION HERE
    }

}

function postTable1Data(id, status, articles, couriername) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "scripts/update.php",
                data: //INSERT DATA HERE - OMITTED
                success: //INSERT DATA HERE - OMITTED
            });     
    }

function postTable2Data(id, type, datetime, location, description) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "scripts/update.php",
                data: //INSERT DATA HERE - OMITTED
                success: //INSERT DATA HERE - OMITTED
            }); 

    }

function postErrorData(id, courier) {

        //POST ERROR DATA - OMITTED

    }

function eraseFoundArticle(id) {
        var arrayIndex = articleArray.indexOf(id);
            articleArray.splice(arrayIndex,1);

    }


function returnCIDs(articleIDs, seperator) {
            var cArticleIDs = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < articleIDs.length; i++) {   
                var cArticleIDs = cArticleIDs + seperator + articleIDs[i] ;
            }
            return cArticleIDs;
}
```

Comment: Great, I tried that before, but used the wrong parameter. It now works. Thank you!