# How to make a function start only after another function fully completed in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function

In the below code I'm tried create a game .when user press the button every time  it will generate a random number between 1 to 3 and add it with the previous score ( 9 is the finishing point ). There also have two function `pump()` and `demotive()` .if the user  reach total point 6 `pump()` will make it to the 8. if user reach 7 the demotive() make it 3.

```js
var k = 0;
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function () {

    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    num = num % 3; /*generate a random no between 0 to 2*/
    num = num + 1; /*generate a random no between 1 to 3*/
    //alert(num);/* check the no*/
    document.getElementById("currnt-value").innerHTML = "you get" + num;
    k = k + num;
    var parent = document.getElementById('a' + k);
    var circle = document.getElementById('crcl');
    parent.appendChild(circle);
    pump(k);
    demotive(k);
});

function pump(val) {
    if (val == 6) {
        alert("you get pumped");
        k = 8;
        var parent = document.getElementById('a' + k);
        var circle = document.getElementById('crcl');
        parent.appendChild(circle);
    }
}

function demotive(val) {

    if (val == 7) {
        alert("oh..!!!you are demotived");
        k = 3;
        var parent = document.getElementById('a' + k);
        var circle = document.getElementById('crcl');
        parent.appendChild(circle);
    }
}
```

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;height:100%;
  }

#board{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  
  }
#one,#two,#three{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
  }
.flag-point{
  width:100px;
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  }
#a8,#a2,#a4,#a6 {
  background-color:green;
  }

#crcl{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:red;
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-radius:50%;
  }
```

```html
<div id="crcl"> </div> <button id="btn">move circle</button><p id="currnt-value"></p> 

<div id="board">
  <div id="one">
    <div id="a9" class="flag-point">9</div>
    <div id="a8" class="flag-point">8</div>
    <div id="a7" class="flag-point">7</div>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <div id="a6" class="flag-point">6</div>
    <div id="a5" class="flag-point">5</div>
    <div id="a4" class="flag-point">4</div>
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    <div id="a3" class="flag-point">3</div>
    <div id="a2" class="flag-point">2</div>
    <div id="a1" class="flag-point">1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But if I'm standing on 4 and if I get a score "two" then directly moved to the 8 instead of 6 => 8 . How can I fix that?.I want to demonstrate both movements(first move from 4 to 6 and then the pumped move from 6 to 8 one by one).How can I achieve that?

Comment: The functions most certainly do not execute in parallel.  They happen one after the other.

Comment: @Pointy sorry I.m new to JS ,that is why I mistaken,is there any way to do one by one,I'm also tried setTimeOut but which didn't help me

Comment: For why `4` and `2` result in `8`, that seems to be precisely the goal of `pump()`, as you stated – `4 + 2` arrives at `6`, then "*if the user reach total point 6 `pump()` will make it to the 8.*."

Comment: @JonathanLonowski yeah i wanna to demonstrate the user reach 6 and the he will get pumped

Comment: @dreamhunter Okay. That's fine, but that behavior being your goal isn't clear from your question.

Comment: @dreamhunter your "click" event handler *always* calls *both* `pump()` and `demotive()`. It's really not very clear what you want that code to do.

Comment: @Pointy i just want to check the current scores reach 6 or 7 and if so take then take the action.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I'm editted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run function after another one completes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144161/run-function-after-another-one-completes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the movement by `pump()` as 2 steps, you'll have to give the UI time to redraw in between the 2 movements. Currently, it won't redraw until the end of the `click` event, when `k` and the circle are already at `8`.

You can give it that time with a brief [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout).

```
function pump(val) {
    if (val == 6) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert("you get pumped");
            k = 8;
            var parent = document.getElementById('a' + k);
            var circle = document.getElementById('crcl');
            parent.appendChild(circle);
        }, 10);
    }
}
```

The delay doesn't have to be long; the `alert()` will hold the user's attention while the circle shows on square 6.

---

Combined with your example:

```js
var k = 0;
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function () {

    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    num = num % 3; /*generate a random no between 0 to 2*/
    num = num + 1; /*generate a random no between 1 to 3*/
    //alert(num);/* check the no*/
    document.getElementById("currnt-value").innerHTML = "you get" + num;
    k = k + num;
    var parent = document.getElementById('a' + k);
    var circle = document.getElementById('crcl');
    parent.appendChild(circle);
    pump(k);
    demotive(k);
});

function pump(val) {
    if (val == 6) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert("you get pumped");
            k = 8;
            var parent = document.getElementById('a' + k);
            var circle = document.getElementById('crcl');
            parent.appendChild(circle);
        }, 200);
    }
}

function demotive(val) {

    if (val == 7) {
        alert("oh..!!!you are demotived");
        k = 3;
        var parent = document.getElementById('a' + k);
        var circle = document.getElementById('crcl');
        parent.appendChild(circle);
    }
}
```

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;height:100%;
  }

#board{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  
  }
#one,#two,#three{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
  }
.flag-point{
  width:100px;
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  }
#a8,#a2,#a4,#a6 {
  background-color:green;
  }

#crcl{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:red;
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-radius:50%;
  }
```

```html
<div id="crcl"> </div> <button id="btn">move circle</button><p id="currnt-value"></p> 

<div id="board">
  <div id="one">
    <div id="a9" class="flag-point">9</div>
    <div id="a8" class="flag-point">8</div>
    <div id="a7" class="flag-point">7</div>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <div id="a6" class="flag-point">6</div>
    <div id="a5" class="flag-point">5</div>
    <div id="a4" class="flag-point">4</div>
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    <div id="a3" class="flag-point">3</div>
    <div id="a2" class="flag-point">2</div>
    <div id="a1" class="flag-point">1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This still gets an error though once you click enough times because he expects `k` to remain within a certain range as per `var parent = document.getElementById('a' + k);` and his div's only go up to `a9`. Perhaps he needs some sort of `if(k>9)k-=9;` or something similar.

Comment: @ultimer really this is a minimized one, I have 10 x 10 board and there is a function to alert you won the game when reach 100.this is just designed to make functionality fully functional.

Comment: @dreamhunter Just in case, bear in mind that it's possible to pass by 100 without landing on it (e.g. when `k` is 99, a `num` greater than 1 skips into invalid territory).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski that is also checked :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can decide weather you want to execute function in parallel or in serial. You can also decide order of execution in case one function is dependent in another.

1. call back function:
   As mentioned above, the call back function will execute once the parent function complete its execution.
2. Promise:
   It is more advanced then callback and you can set dependent function
   like

   `promise.all(fun1,  fun2, ...).then(fun3)
   promise.when(fun1).then(fun2)`
3. Observable:
   RxJs observable is also provides such mechanism and can be explore

Other option you can explore if exist.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can add callback to your javascript function so it will be executed in order.

for example

```
function pump(param, callback){
    //do something here with your param

    callback();
}

function demotive(param){
    //do something
}

//call the function in order pump, then demotive after pump finishes
pump(1, function(){
    demotive(4);
});
```

this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190850/create-a-custom-callback-in-javascript) also will help

Comment: but in javascript most function is called one after another without waiting previous function to finish. this effect of asynchronous will be seen clearly if you have function with big loops

Comment: @Kebeng the effect of asynchronous will only be there if we have a ajax call or a api hit. Otherwise javascript functions work synchronously