# Vue Js - Sending axios request after file input changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-component, image-uploading

**EDIT**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144161/run-function-after-another-one-completes) does solve a problem on running two different functions back to back. Nevertheless, my question deals specifically with the behavior of a file handling input and the moment in which to chain a second event (solved by the second example in @Igor 's answer).

**QUESTION**

I have a file upload Vue component which works perfectly fine. The improvement I would like to make is for it to work on "one click", meaning the `upload()` method should be triggered in response to the `createImage()` finishing. How would I do that?

```
<template>
<div>
    <div>
        <label>Image:</label>
        <img :src="(image) ? image : tempImage" class="img-fluid">
        <div class="custom-file">
            <input type="file" v-on:change="onFileChange" class="custom-file-input"
            :class="{ 'border-0':image }">
            <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">
                {{ filename ? filename : 'Choose pic' }}
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" 
        :disabled="!image"
        @click.prevent="upload">
            Upload
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        props: ['tempImage'],
        data(){
            return {
                image: '',
                filename: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            onFileChange(e) {
                let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
                this.$parent.uploading = true;
                if (!files.length)
                    return;
                this.createImage(files[0]);
            },
            createImage(file) {
                let reader = new FileReader();
                let vm = this;
                reader.onload = (e) => {
                    vm.image = e.target.result;
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                vm.filename = file.name;
            },
            upload(){
                console.log(this.image);
                axios.post('/api/upload',{image: this.image}).then(res => {
                    if( !res.data.errors ){
                       this.$parent.tempData.image = res.data.src;
                       this.$parent.uploading = false;
                    } else {
                        console.log(res.data.errors);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run function after another one completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144161/run-function-after-another-one-completes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about calling `upload()` from `createImage()`?

```
createImage(file) {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  let vm = this;
  reader.onload = (e) => {
    vm.image = e.target.result;
    vm.filename = file.name;
    this.upload();
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Or passing `upload()` as a callback:

```
onFileChange(e) {
  let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
  this.$parent.uploading = true;
  if (!files.length)
    return;
  this.createImage(files[0], this.upload);
},
createImage(file, callback) {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  let vm = this;
  reader.onload = (e) => {
    vm.image = e.target.result;
    vm.filename = file.name;
    if (callback) callback();
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rcn3veb1/)

Comment: I had already tried your first approach without success since the `image` is empty at the time `upload()` is called (which is why `image` is logged). Tried the second one, turns out the same.

Answer (score 0):

You start off by **creating a variable** `isUploading` with an initial value of `false`. Then in your method `upload` you first **check** if the `isUploading` variable is false, **if it is false**, start **upload**, otherwise, either do nothing or **inform the user** that the page is still uploading image.

The code could look like this:

```js
var isUploading = false;
export default {
  // ...
  upload() {
    // If not uploading anything start the upload
    if (!isUploading) {
      isUploading = true;
      console.log(this.image);
      axios.post('/api/upload', {
        image: this.image
      }).then(res => {
        if (!res.data.errors) {
          this.$parent.tempData.image = res.data.src;
          this.$parent.uploading = false;
        } else {
          console.log(res.data.errors);
        }
      });
    } else {
      // Do other stuff here
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```