# using jQuery, how to wait for onChange event to finish before form submit event is fired

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose there is a textbox in my webpage and I have attached an 'change' event on this textbox using jQuery.

```
$('.myFormClass').on('change', '.amount', function () {            
    // Some AJAX call here, and the response is assigned to a variable
});
```

And I have a form submit event as well,

```
$('.myFormClass').on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
  // some code in which I use the response from the earlier AJAX call returned against 'change' event
});
```

The issue is that the 'change' event works fine individually but when form submitted they are fired almost simultaneously and till the time when AJAX call against the 'change' event is returned back (supposed to be), the form had already been submitted by then so I can't use the AJAX response, which is needed before the form submission.

Is there something built-in jQuery for this situation? If no, any alternate efficient solution?

Comment: register your `.submit()` method inside your first `ajax` call `success` function

Comment: @VasuKuncham Your suggestion is invalid in my case because I do NOT want to submit the form on every `onChange `event, rather when the user intends to actually submit the form using conventional methods.

Answer (score 0):

Add a button. When the user click the button a boolean is set to tru and if it is true then only submit will happen otherwise only onchange function will work not the submit function.

```js
var sub=false;
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button').click(function(){sub=true;console.log(sub)})
$('.myFormClass').on('change', '.amount', function () {            
    // Some AJAX call here, and the response is assigned to a variable
    console.log('changed')
});

$('.myFormClass').keypress((e)=>{if(e.keyCode=='13'){e.preventDefault();console.log('not submitted on enter')}})
$('.myFormClass').click( function (e) {

e.preventDefault();
console.log("submit cancelled")
if(sub)
  $(this).submit();
  // some code in which I use the response from the earlier AJAX call returned against 'change' event

});

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="myFormClass">
aa
<input class="amount">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<button>Want to submit the form?</button>
```

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`

Comment: Because i have not created the ajax call. It just states that on success of the ajax submit has to be called

Comment: oh sorry my bad

Comment: This solution will not work because I do NOT want to submit the form on every `onChange` event, rather when the user intends to actually submit the form using conventional methods.

Comment: @AshayMandwarya Your edit will not work when the form is submitted through ENTER key.

Comment: Check the edits now. Working for enter keypress also

Answer (score 0):

Store the ajax promise and wait for its resolve in the form submit handler

```js
let amountReady = null;

$('.testForm').on('change', '.amount', function(ev) {
  amountReady = $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://httpbin.org/post',
    data: {
      amount: $(this).val()
    }
  });
});


$('.testForm').on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!amountReady) return;
  amountReady.then((amountAjaxResult) => {
    console.log('submit now', amountAjaxResult.form.amount);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="testForm">
  <form>
    <input type="number" class="amount" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
function method1(){
   // some code

}

function method2(){
   // some code
}

$.ajax({
   url:method1(),
   success:function(){
   method2();
}
})
```

Or nested function after a function is done with:

```js
function test () {
    console.log('test');   
}

function test2 (callback) {
    console.log('test2');
    callback();
}


test2(test);
```

Might be [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144161/run-function-after-another-one-completes)

Comment: i would also do it on your first solution

Comment: Your answer is out of context. Go through the question again.

Comment: I'm not sure what is your issue with my answer but you clearly stated: "The issue is that the 'change' event **works fine individually** but ***when form submitted they are fired almost simultaneously*** and till the time **when AJAX call against the 'change' event is returned back** (supposed to be), the **form had already been submitted** by then **so I can't use the AJAX response**, which is needed before the form submission." Just use nested to make sure they're dealt with then get the response.